# Erlang Looping through a list (or set) to process files

Tags: variables, for-loop, erlang, user-defined-functions

I want to create 16 directories in Erlang.
for ( create_dir("work/p" ++ A, where A is an element in a list [0, 1, ... f]) (sixteen number in hex notation).

I could of course write sixteen lines like: mkdir ("work/p0"), mkdir("work/p1") etc.

I have looked at lists:foreach. In the examples fun is used, is possible to define a function outside the loop and call it?

I am new to Erlang and used to C++ etc.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible to define a (named) function outside the call to `lists:foreach/2`. Why would you, though? This is a case when an anonymous function is incredibly handy:

```
lists:foreach(fun(N) ->
                  file:make_dir(
                      filename:join("work", "p"++integer_to_list(N, 16)))
              end, lists:seq(0, 15)).
```

The `filename:join/2` call will use the appropriate directory separator to construct the string `work/pN`, where `N` is an integer in hex representation constructed using `integer_to_list/2`, which converts an integer to a string (list) in a given base (16).

`lists:seq/2` is a friendly little function that returns the list `[A,A+1,A+2,...,B-1,B]` given `A` and `B`.

Note that you could just as well have used the [list comprehension](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html) syntax here, but since we're applying functions to a list for the side-effects alone, I chose to stick with a `foreach`.

If you *really* want to define a separate function -- let's call it `foo` and assume it takes 42 arguments -- you can refer to it as `fun foo/42` in your code. This expression evaluates to a function object that, like an anonymous function defined inline, can be passed to `lists:foreach/2`.